# compare phone number in android contacts database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a phone number with country code like +91XXXXXXXXXX. and a phone number in my android contacts database is in the form of XX XX XXXXXX. How to compare them in sqlite database query.
Any help would be appreciable....

I need this to update or delete the existing phone number in android database.

**Note**

```
Phone number can be of any country. Above is just the example.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try the code below

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode("Pass phone number here"));
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.NUMBER}, null, null, null);
if(c.getCount()>0){
    c.moveToFirst(); 
    System.out.println(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.NUMBER)));
}
c.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

There can be multiple ways to do this:

As you see below here:

```
String yourInputString = "+91XXXXXXXXXX";
String dbContactString = "XX XX XXXXXX";
```

both have different format; so we must have to extract substring ("XXXXXXXXXX") from first string and also have to remove whitespaces ("XXXXXXXXXX") from the second string!

```
yourInputString = yourInputString.substring(2); // 2 is start index  and result will be "XXXXXXXXXX" 
dbContactString = dbContactString.replaceAll("\\s+",""); // replaces all whitespaces and result will be "XXXXXXXXXX"
```

now, both have same format so you can easily compare them with equals().

`yourInputString.equals(dbContactString)` is the way.

It returns true if yourInputString is equals to dbContactString in value. Else, it will return false.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your answer. But the phone number is not only having +91. It can be of any country.

Comment: for that i think you have to do alot of work....  btw. why don't you store the phone number with format +91XXXXXXXXXX in your contact database from where you are inserting it. it will be easy to compare in that way.

Comment: or could you tell me that will your phone number always starts with '+' char , input that you 'll be comparing with contact db or tell me could you change your contact db's phone numbers format?

Comment: another solution will be that: remove all whitespaces from contactDbString and in your inputString = ; //substring (last 10 digits);                                    like this:                                                                                         inputString = inputString.substring(inputString.length()-10, inputString.length()); and compare it the same way.

Comment: Many countries have number which are not of length 10 and we cannot insert with appending "+XX"  at the beginning of the string, since we may not know which country or locale the number belongs to.